# Width 100%, center wont work

Tags: html

I have a problem with HTML.

The #content div wont get the width.
div test is centered, and #menu should have 15% width and #info to.
I tried clear: both; but it wont work...
Maybe its a issue to width 100%.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;

    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: green;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#upper {
    height: 15%;

    background-color: blue;
}

#test {
    height: 85%;

    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#test #menu {
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;

    float: left;

    /* scroll bar */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    background-color: red;
}

#test #content {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;

    float: left;
}

#test #content {
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;

    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="upper">
        upper
        <!-- logo etc -->
    </div>
    <div id="test">
        <div id="menu">
            menu
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            content
        </div>
        <div id="info">
            info
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could somebody help me!

Comment: post it from jsfiddle .. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yooouuri/gMMHL/

Comment: see this http://jsbin.com/AGIYImi/1/

Comment: For the one who whants to see the online version!

http://moblife.nl/version-2.0/

Again big thanks!

Comment: your are welcome my friend :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are overwriting your declarations:

```
#test #content {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;

    float: left;
}

#test #content {
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;

    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Use of `inline-block` on the element instead of floating.
although it has is own faults..

http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/gMMHL/1/

Answer (score -1):

Auto margins don't work with percentages. You'll have to give it a fixed dimension in order for the margin centering to work.

Comment: i have all responsive layout with percentages, and auto margins do work.

Comment: Misunderstood your problem!